# unable to post values to php page

Tags: php, post

I am working on a php web service which should accept some parameters as post but somehow it doesn't accept any of my variables sent as post. Can anyone please check my code and let me know the mistake I am making.

```
<?php
echo "register string\n";
require_once('config.php');
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
echo "test 123\n";

function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

$fbid = clean($_POST['fbid']);
echo $fbid;
$fname = clean($_POST['first_name']);
echo $fname;
```

?>
echo $fbid or echo $fname are not displayed. I am using SOAPUI to test the web services.

**Update1:** I am getting following errors when I added error reporting:

```
Array
```

(
)
register string
test 123

**Notice**:  Undefined index: fbid in **/home/tapoint/public_html/tapadmin/webservices/register.php** on line **23**

**Warning**:  mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'tapoint'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in **/home/tapoint/public_html/tapadmin/webservices/register.php** on line **20**

**Warning**:  mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in **/home/tapoint/public_html/tapadmin/webservices/register.php** on line **20**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: first_name in **/home/tapoint/public_html/tapadmin/webservices/register.php** on line **25**

**Warning**:  mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'tapoint'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in **/home/tapoint/public_html/tapadmin/webservices/register.php** on line **20**

**Warning**:  mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in **/home/tapoint/public_html/tapadmin/webservices/register.php** on line **20**

Regards
Pankaj

Comment: `trim` doesnt generate any level of error..theres no need for `@`

Comment: Try error_reporting(E_ALL); on first line to see if something goes wrong

Comment: And do a print_r($_POST); to see what POST variables you've got

Comment: I am not receiving anything in post and getting some errors

Comment: Did you check that you are actually doing a post request? You can inspect it using the development tools in your browser.

Comment: I am checking it in SOAPUI, may be I should try something else, also I can see a mysql connection error but I my login credentials are correct.

Comment: If you have had an error with mysqli_connect(), mysql_real_escape_string() didn't work. Try to echo $_POST['fbid'] at the beginning of your script to double check.

Comment: I am getting: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: fbid in <b>/home/tapoint/public_html/tapadmin/webservices/register.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />

Comment: I just tested it in postman in my browser and I am getting values in post array as following: Array
(
    [fbid] => 111111
    [first_name] => pankaj
)

Comment: but I am getting access denied to mysql probably because of this execution is failing beyond this